# SQL Server: trying to create view inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, view

I'm trying to create my view inside the stored procedure but I faced an error .

My code is :

```
    alter PROCEDURE p.Azmoon1 
    AS
    begin
       EXEC ('IF OBJECT_ID (''r.r_Sales01_Requests__Duplicates'', ''V'') IS NOT NULL
            DROP VIEW r.r_Sales01_Requests__Duplicates ;
            go
            create view r.r_Sales01_Requests__Duplicates ( 
             CompanyID
            ,Branch
            ,Year
            ,VoucherType,VoucherNumber
            ,Date_Persian
            ,Row
        ) as
        select 
             CompanyID
            ,Branch
            ,Year
            ,VoucherType,VoucherNumber
            ,Date_Persian
            ,Row
        from t_SalesRequests
        group by CompanyID,Branch,Year,VoucherType,VoucherNumber,Date_Persian,Row
        having count(*)>1

        go

    ')
    end
```

When I call my procedure like below :

```
execute p.Azmoon1
```

I got these errors:

> Incorrect syntax near 'go'
>   'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>   Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

Comment: Why do you want to create a view *inside* a stored procedure? Doesn't make any sense.... if you need a view inside a stored procedure - can't you just use a CTE (Common Table Expression) instead?

Comment: The reason for the error is the fact that `GO` is **not** a valid SQL keyword - it's a delimiter that's available in SQL Server **Management Studio** only ....

Comment: @marc_s i want to create view in store procedure because i have almost over 2500 views to create and i want changed their schema easily later .

Comment: HUH? Your explanation of why you are creating a view from a stored procedure doesn't make any sense at all. How does creating the view from a stored procedure make it easier to change the schema later?

Comment: i create my view as stored procedure which has 2 arguments i.e SchemaName and ViewName and i will call my store procedure such as Execute procedure @schema,@viewName and i will create my view , if i wanna change all my views schema i just need to change my variable (@schema) value to change it ,

Comment: Are you sure you can pass a view name as a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the "Go" as @mark_s rightly mentioned it is not a SQL keyword that is executable in EXEC.

I created the below procedure to modify the view much like you have. Except that instead of using a 'Go", I am using two separate EXEC statements.

```
create procedure [dbo].[CreateInvoiceView]
as 
begin
    Exec ('If object_ID(''invoices'',''V'') is not null 
            drop view invoices;')

    Exec ('
        create view [dbo].[Invoices] AS
           SELECT Orders.ShipName as SHIP_Name, Orders.ShipAddress, Orders.ShipCity, Orders.ShipRegion, Orders.ShipPostalCode,Orders.ShipCountry, Orders.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName AS CustomerName, Customers.Address, Customers.City, Customers.Region, Customers.PostalCode, Customers.Country, (FirstName + '' '' + LastName) AS Salesperson, Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Orders.RequiredDate, Orders.ShippedDate, Shippers.CompanyName As ShipperName
            FROM    Shippers INNER JOIN 
                    (Products INNER JOIN 
                       (
                       (Employees INNER JOIN 
                       (Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID) 
                              ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID) 
                              INNER JOIN "Order Details" ON Orders.OrderID = "Order Details".OrderID) 
                              ON Products.ProductID = "Order Details".ProductID) 
                              ON Shippers.ShipperID = Orders.ShipVia

    ')
end
```